# Solidity code for byte manipulation fail to compile using hardhat compiler with solidity 0.8.0

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, hardhat

I am compiling code from OpenSea project written in `Sol 0.5.0` using `0.8.0` compiler, and I'm getting error:

```
  ParserError: Expected primary expression.
--> contracts/Strings.sol:53:25:
 |
53 |             bstr[k--] = byte(uint8(48 + _i % 10));
 |                         ^^^^


Error HH600: Compilation failed
```

The original code is found at: https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures/blob/master/contracts/Strings.sol, it uses `Sol 0.5.0` and is presumably compiled with truffle. I am attempting to use `Hardhat` and `0.8.0`. The code is reproduced below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

library Strings {
  // via https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/blob/master/oraclizeAPI_0.5.sol
  function strConcat(string memory _a, string memory _b, string memory _c, string memory _d, string memory _e) internal pure returns (string memory) {
      bytes memory _ba = bytes(_a);
      bytes memory _bb = bytes(_b);
      bytes memory _bc = bytes(_c);
      bytes memory _bd = bytes(_d);
      bytes memory _be = bytes(_e);
      string memory abcde = new string(_ba.length + _bb.length + _bc.length + _bd.length + _be.length);
      bytes memory babcde = bytes(abcde);
      uint k = 0;
      for (uint i = 0; i < _ba.length; i++) babcde[k++] = _ba[i];
      for (uint i = 0; i < _bb.length; i++) babcde[k++] = _bb[i];
      for (uint i = 0; i < _bc.length; i++) babcde[k++] = _bc[i];
      for (uint i = 0; i < _bd.length; i++) babcde[k++] = _bd[i];
      for (uint i = 0; i < _be.length; i++) babcde[k++] = _be[i];
      return string(babcde);
    }

    function strConcat(string memory _a, string memory _b, string memory _c, string memory _d) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        return strConcat(_a, _b, _c, _d, "");
    }

    function strConcat(string memory _a, string memory _b, string memory _c) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        return strConcat(_a, _b, _c, "", "");
    }

    function strConcat(string memory _a, string memory _b) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        return strConcat(_a, _b, "", "", "");
    }

    function uint2str(uint _i) internal pure returns (string memory _uintAsString) {
        if (_i == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        uint j = _i;
        uint len;
        while (j != 0) {
            len++;
            j /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory bstr = new bytes(len);
        uint k = len - 1;
        while (_i != 0) {
            bstr[k--] = byte(uint8(48 + _i % 10));
            _i /= 10;
        }
        return string(bstr);
    }
}
```

Note I changed the `pragma` up top. everything looks fine to me so I'm not sure where the issue is aside from the fact that it's on this line:   `bstr[k--] = byte(uint8(48 + _i % 10));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `bytes1` instead of `byte`.

---

> The type `byte` has been removed. It was an alias of `bytes1`.

Source: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/080-breaking-changes.html#silent-changes-of-the-semantics